# Statistics for completed queues on RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

If I go on the RabbitMQ Management UI and go to queues I can see message rate since I opened the window but I can't see any information about how many queues failed or were successful.

I'd be interesting to see how many messages/queues were processed, failed and completed each second, minute, hour, day... on RabbitMQ. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Management plugin has an HTTP API, which you can query to receive queue/exchange stats. See the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184385/how-can-i-get-the-rabbitmq-queue-acknowledge-statistics for an example or two.